# Call all Inputs but Exclude Submit button for function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use

```
$("input").on("keyup", function(){
```

but to still some how exclude a certain input. I have many inputs and the only one that I do not want it to apply to is

```
<input type="submit" name="submit"
```

Is it possible to somehow exclude only the submit input button?

```
var exclude = $('input') !== submit;
exclude.on("keyup", function(){
```

This was along the lines I was thinking but its still wrong as you can see.

Comment: jQuery does provide the API for that - `.not`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('input').not('[type="submit"]').on("keyup", function(){})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. jQuery provides a `.not` API which takes the input as `css-selector` for which elements you want to exclude from selection

```
$("input").not('input[type=submit]').on("keyup", function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just CSS selector:

```
$("input:not([type=submit])").on("keyup", function(){
```